# How can I delay the time of creating line in canvas in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, time

I want to create one line in canvas in one second and another line in another second.
But my code shows all of the lines in one second after delaying 1 second.
In every second I want to create only one line in canvas according to these (everysecond) coordinate.
I am using for loop to create line 60 line inside the canvas.

---

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
everysecond = [(99), (27),
               (107), (29),
               (115), (29),
               (122), (33),
               (129), (35),
               (135), (38),
               (142), (43),
               (147), (48),
               (153), (52),
               (157), (57),
               (161), (64),
               (165), (72),
               (168), (79),
               (169), (85),
               (171), (92),
               (169), (99),
               (171), (108),
               (169), (115),
               (168), (123),
               (165), (130),
               (160), (134),
               (158), (142),
               (153), (147),
               (148), (154),
               (142), (158),
               (136), (160),
               (129), (166),
               (122), (168),
               (114), (170),
               (107), (170),
               (100), (169),
               (92), (169),
               (85), (170),
               (79), (168),
               (72), (166),
               (67), (160),
               (58), (158),
               (52), (153),
               (48), (148),
               (43), (142),
               (38), (134),
               (33), (128),
               (34), (121),
               (30), (114),
               (31), (107),
               (29), (102),
               (30), (91),
               (31), (86),
               (32), (79),
               (35), (70),
               (36), (70),
               (44), (58),
               (47), (53),
               (53), (47),
               (58), (41),
               (63), (37),
               (71), (34),
               (78), (32),
               (85), (30),
               (92), (29)]


def second():
    j = 1
    k = 0
    for i in range(0, 60):
      canvas.create_line((everysecond[k], everysecond[j], 100, 100), width=2, fill='red')
      j = j + 2
      k = k + 2
canvas.after(1000, second)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It showed the error:`NameError: name 'j' is not defined`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA sorry sir this is my first question in stackoverflow , and  tab(space) is not correct while posting question . So, can you help me now? i have gave the correct code now.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `k` and `j` as the arguments in the `after`.like:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

line_id = []

everysecond = [(99), (27),
               (107), (29),
               (115), (29),
               (122), (33),
               (129), (35),
               (135), (38),
               (142), (43),
               (147), (48),
               (153), (52),
               (157), (57),
               (161), (64),
               (165), (72),
               (168), (79),
               (169), (85),
               (171), (92),
               (169), (99),
               (171), (108),
               (169), (115),
               (168), (123),
               (165), (130),
               (160), (134),
               (158), (142),
               (153), (147),
               (148), (154),
               (142), (158),
               (136), (160),
               (129), (166),
               (122), (168),
               (114), (170),
               (107), (170),
               (100), (169),
               (92), (169),
               (85), (170),
               (79), (168),
               (72), (166),
               (67), (160),
               (58), (158),
               (52), (153),
               (48), (148),
               (43), (142),
               (38), (134),
               (33), (128),
               (34), (121),
               (30), (114),
               (31), (107),
               (29), (102),
               (30), (91),
               (31), (86),
               (32), (79),
               (35), (70),
               (36), (70),
               (44), (58),
               (47), (53),
               (53), (47),
               (58), (41),
               (63), (37),
               (71), (34),
               (78), (32),
               (85), (30),
               (92), (29)]


def second(k, j):
    line_id.append(canvas.create_line((everysecond[k], everysecond[j], 100, 100), width=2, fill='red'))
    if j == len(everysecond)-1:
        for id in line_id:
            canvas.delete(id)
        canvas.after(100, second, 0, 1)
    else:
        canvas.after(100, second, k + 2, j + 2)

canvas.after(100, second, 0, 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Kshitiz That's easy, check the number `j` and delete all the items on the `canvas` when `everysecond[j]` is the last element.

Comment: @Kshitiz Save them in a list, and delete all of them by `for` loop.

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: But i don't need it, I want to delete the previous canvas.line and create the new canvas.line according to everysecond
Your creation is just delete all the canvas if it rotact 360 degree but i want is delete in every second and create.canvas in same second when it is deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218160/discussion-between-kshitiz-and-jizhihaosama).